Alternative to pairwise summation for aggregating scalar products of multiple vectors
There is a problem involving the aggregation of high-dimensional vectors in a way that avoids the computational cost of pairwise summation. Specifically, each data point is represented by a 16-dimensional vector, and I have a symmetric metric matrix $ \mathbf{G} $ which allows me to calculate the scalar product between any two vectors $ \mathbf{v}_i $ and $ \mathbf{v}_j $ using the bilinear form:
$$ S_{ij} = \mathbf{v}_i^T \mathbf{G} \mathbf{v}_j $$
To assess the overall scalar product of a group of $ n $ vectors, there could be an approach involving calculating pairwise scalar products and averaging them:
$$ S_T = \frac{2}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} S_{ij} $$
However, this pairwise summation approach is computationally expensive, especially for large $ n $. One idea is to transform the vectors into a different form for which linear operations can be applied.
Specifically, I'm considering:

Transforming each vector $ \mathbf{v}_i $ into a new representation $ \mathbf{A}_i $.
Aggregating these transformed representations (e.g., summing or averaging).
Inversely transforming the aggregate back to the original space or a meaningful scalar product measure.

Are there established methods or mathematical frameworks that support such transformations? Any suggestions or explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

The number you want to compute can be computed from $v^T G v$ where $v = v_1 + \dots + v_n$, together with $v_i^T G v_i$ for all $i$ since it looks like you want to ignore the diagonal. That should save you from having to do $O(n^2)$ inner products, now you only need $O(n)$.

Everything to know and experiment is the central part of all CAS systems, see e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummationTransforms.html
